# Unexpected output in php function

Tags: php, function

Here is a simple function which i made on PHP. The problem is that it is giving totally unexepected output.

From my database it takes $takings = 242 and $cost = 81 so it should show 242-81=161 as answer. but instead it is showing 242. What can be the problem ?

```
function differences($takings,$cost)
{
$difference = $takings - $cost;

if($difference < 0)
{
    $color = red;
    $difference = '$'.$difference.'million';
}

elseif($difference > 0)
{
   $color = green;
   $difference = '$'.$difference.='million';
}   

elseif($difference = 0)
{
   $color = blue;
   $difference = "broken even ";
}

return '<span style="color:'.$color.';">'.$difference.'</span>';
}
```

Guys. here is the complete code for the page. When open the page in the browser it shows this : [image]

```
<?php

function getdirector($director)
{
global $db;
$query = 'select name from peopledb where peopleid = '.$director;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error($db));
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
extract($row);
return $name;
}

function getactor($actor)
{
$query = 'select name from peopledb where peopleid = '.$actor;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error($db));
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
extract($row);
return $name;
}


function getmovietype($type)
{
$query = 'select movietype from movietype where movieid = '.$type;
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error($db));
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
extract($row);
return $movietype;
}


function differences($takings,$cost)
{
$difference = $takings - $cost;

if($difference < 0)
{
    $color = red;
    $difference = '$'.$difference.'million';
}

elseif($difference > 0)
{
   $color = green;
   $difference = '$'.$difference.='million';
}   

elseif($difference = 0)
{
   $color = blue;
   $difference = "broken even ";
}

return '<span style="color:'.$color.';">'.$difference.'</span>';
}


$abc = $_GET['movieid'];


$db = mysql_connect('localhost','root','saw123') or die('Connection error');
mysql_select_db("moviesite",$db) or die(mysyql_error($db));
$query = "select moviename,releaseyear,director,actor,type,movierunningtime,moviecost,movietakings from movie where movieid = ". $abc;




$result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die(mysql_error($db));

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$movie_name = $row['moviename'];
$movie_director = getdirector($row['director']);
$movie_releaseyear = $row['releaseyear'];
$movie_actor = getactor($row['actor']);
$movie_type = getmovietype($row['type']);
$movie_runningtime = $row['movierunningtime'].' minutes';
$movie_cost =$row['moviecost'].'million';
$movie_takings = $row['movietakings'].'million';
$movie_health = differences($row['movietakings'],$row['movie_cost']);



echo <<<ENDHTML
<html>
 <head>
   <title> Details and Reviews for the movies for $movie_name </title>
  </head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<h2>$movie_name</h2>
<h3> details </h3>
<table cellpadding = "1" cellspacing = "4"
style = "width = 80% ;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;";>
<tr>
 <td><strong>Title</strong></strong></td>
 <td>$movie_name</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td><strong>release date</strong></strong></td>
 <td>$movie_releaseyear</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<tr>
 <td><strong>movie director</strong></strong></td>
 <td>$movie_director</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<tr>
 <td><strong>Lead Actor</strong></strong></td>
 <td>$movie_actor</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<tr>
 <td><strong>Running time</strong></strong></td>
 <td>$movie_runningtime</td>
</tr>
<tr>


<tr>
 <td><strong>Cost</strong></strong></td>
 <td>$movie_cost</td>
</tr>
<tr>


<tr>
 <td><strong>Takings</strong></strong></td>
 <td>$movie_takings</td>
</tr>
<tr>

<tr>
 <td><strong>Health</strong></strong></td>
 <td>$movie_health</td>
</tr>
<tr>


</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
ENDHTML;



$table = <<<ENDHTML
<div style="text-align: center;">
<h2>The Ultimate movie database</h2>
<table border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='2'
       style="width: 70%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

<tr>
<th>Movie ID </th>
<th>Movie title</th>
<th>year of release </th>
<th>Movie director</th>
<th>Movie Actor</th>
<th>Movie type</th>
</tr>
ENDHTML;

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried outputting the `$takings` and `$cost` variables? If you have 242, and you *think* you're subtracting 61, but the result is still 242, you obviously aren't subtracting what you think you're subtracting. Presumably, `$cost` is 0, which means the error in logic lies outside this function. A little debugging would probably tell you what is wrong.

Comment: `var_dump` or `output` the parameters, just before the function call.

Comment: Show us how are you fetching data and calling this function, most probably you have typo in variable name and you are passing null instead fo real `$cost`

Comment: `$difference = 0` should be `$difference == 0` also, but I think that's unrelated to your issue.

Comment: Use some IDE (like NetBeans PHP) to avoid mistakes like @zdhickman pointed (assign instead of comparison).

Comment: @zdhickman A good catch, but not the problem in this case; that bug will just cause a result that nothing will ever show a "blue".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$movie_health = differences($row['movietakings'],$row['movie_cost']);`

should be

`$movie_health = differences($row['movietakings'],$row['moviecost']);`

Notice the last variable.

Answer (score 0):

As @dev-null-dweller pointed out, you're likely not actually passing in `(242, 81)`. Write a unit test and you'll find the function works as you expect when given valid inputs.

```
<?php

function differences($takings,$cost)
{
  $difference = $takings - $cost;

  if($difference < 0) {
    $color = 'red';
    $difference = '$'.$difference.'million';
  } elseif($difference > 0) {
   $color = 'green';
   $difference = '$'.$difference.='million';
  } elseif($difference == 0) {
   $color = 'blue';
   $difference = "broken even ";
  }

  return '<span style="color:'.$color.';">'.$difference.'</span>';
}

class DifferencesTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
  public function testValidInput() {
    $this->assertEquals('<span style="color:green;">$161million</span>', differences(242,81));
  }

  public function testInvalidInput() {
    $this->assertEquals('<span style="color:green;">$242million</span>', differences(242,NULL));
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a wild guess. Though likely as it may be, without all the information it's just an assumption and should be up there in the comments.

Comment: The OP's question was "What can be the problem ?", and this addresses the most likely problem. It's easy to repro by passing in `(242, NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$movie_cost =$row['moviecost'].'million';
$movie_takings = $row['movietakings'].'million';
$movie_health = differences($row['movietakings'],$row['movie_cost']);
```

To clarify my earlier answer: note the presences of an underscore in 'movie_cost', and the lack of one in 'moviecost'.

Comment: Also, the code needs help in a lot of other ways; for example, using the soft-deprecated "mysql_" API; using extract() blindly; plenty of opportunities for SQL injection; using nested queries intead of joins...the list could go on. Maybe try [finding a mentor]( http://phpmentoring.org) to help you with some of this stuff.

Answer (score -1):

I think value are not assigned to cost variable.so check to echo cost variable in function.